# insertRowBefore() not displaying values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can someone advise what I am doing wrong with the following code please?
I know it's simple but I think I've been staring at the screen for too long!

```
function addDelivery() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet7");

  var range = srcSheet.getRange("B3:J3").getValues();
  srcSheet.insertRowBefore(6);
  srcSheet.getRange(6,2,1,4).setValues([['B3', 'C3', 'D3', 'E3' , 'F3' , 'G3' , 'H3' , 'I3' , 'J3']]);
```

I'm obviously trying to append the values in cells B3:J3, not have it show B3, C3, D3 etc in the appended row!

Comment: RE:"I am obviously trying..." - well, you obviously try to do just that :) Your code does what you told it to do: insert an empty row before row 6, then get *6th row* (which is now the appended row, btw) and write a row of values B3, C3, etc to it

Comment: Besides, the `range` here is a two-dimensional array of values, remove the `getValues()` and call `setValues()` on that `range`, not the one that is returned via `getRange(6,2,1,4)`

Answer (score 3):

Using getRange() and setValues() together

```
function addDelivery() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet7");
  srcSheet.insertRowBefore(6);
```

First Parameter is row 3

Second Parameter is column B or 2

Third Parameter is number of rows which is 1

Fourth Parameter is number of columns which 9

```
  srcSheet.getRange(3,2,1,9).setValues([['B3', 'C3', 'D3', 'E3' , 'F3' , 'G3' , 'H3' , 'I3' , 'J3']]);
```

You could have also done it this way to keep from having to count

```
var data=[['B3', 'C3', 'D3', 'E3' , 'F3' , 'G3' , 'H3' , 'I3' , 'J3']];
srcSheet.getRange(3,2,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

[Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

[Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: Thank-you for your answer Cooper. I believe I found my own solution to get it working, but your code is certainly more efficient  -thanks.

Comment: This is something I had a lot of trouble with when I first came to Google  Apps Script.  I found the debugger to be very help at giving me an image of what the Spreadsheet arrays look like.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the post. 
The answer was obvious....

```
srcSheet.getRange(6,2,1,9).setValues(range);
```

Was as simple as that!

Hope this helps someone.

Best regards manc